# Searching and extracting from a String using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following string in PHP:

```
$cars = "Ford Chevrolet Dodge Chrysler";
```

I am required to output which words have various properties such as: Which word ends in 'let'? Or which word starts with 'Fo'?

I am unsure how to approach this. I am familiar enough with regex formatting, and I have gotten my preg_match to identify matches, but that's only results given in 1 or 0.

So should I split up the words using the space as a delimiter and search each one for matches individually? Or is there a simpler way of going about this?

I am aware of the preg_split function, but I don't know how to actually access the split strings.

```
$cars = "Ford Chevrolet Dodge Chrysler";
$param1 = '/(let)+/';
$param2 = '/(fo)+/';

echo preg_match($param1, $cars);
echo preg_match($param2, $cars);
```

I am aware that this doesn't work, but it prints 1s and verifys to me that matches are being found for both parameters. I just don't know how to extract the full 'Chevrolet' and full 'Ford' for parameter 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Show your `preg_match()` code.

Comment: Use `preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches);`. If there's a match, `$matches` will be a multidimensional array, use `print_r($matches)` to get an idea...

Comment: @HamZa I have tried that, but that only shows me the 'let' rather than the full word Chevrolet.

Comment: @l'L'l I am required to use regex in this situation, otherwise I would have done that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you're going to be able to figure out how to insert user input into variables `$start` or `$end` – just in case: ask them if they want the input string at the beginning or at the end, and based on the answer, save the string to search in to either `$start` or `$end`.

```
$string = "Ford Chevrolet Dodge Chrysler";
$start = "";
$end = "let";

if(!empty($start))
    preg_match_all("#" . $start . "\w+#", $string, $matches);
elseif(!empty($end))
    preg_match_all("#\w+" . $end ."#", $string, $matches);
else
    die("Nothing has been set!");

print_r($matches);
```

This is the case implemented for all the words ending with a `let` in your example string. Bear in mind the regex is only going to match word characters. If you're going to get more complicated strings, maybe another solution should be created.

---

To simply echo all the matches, use foreach loop like this instead of the `print_r` function:

```
if(!empty($matches))
{
    foreach($matches as $match)
        echo $match . "<br>";
}
else
    die("Nothing matched!");
```

Comment: Perfect, that works great. So I get the output Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Chevrolet ) )

How can I reference the 'Chevrolet' for use in a simple echo statement?

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you! Another quick question, what are the # signs in the regex? I understand that the start and end are being concatenated to them, but I don't have experience with those in my limited time with php and regex.

Comment: `#` sign is basically the equivalent of `/` at the beginning and the end. `preg_match("#.*#", $string);` is the same as `preg_match("/.*/", $string);`. It just seems more readable to me with the pound signs.

Comment: @Burninrock24 please accept the answer if you're contented with the results.

Comment: The echo statement is just outputting 'Array'. I simply copy and pasted for a test run, is there anything else I should be aware of?

edit: Just switched $matches to $matches[0] and it seems to work now.

Comment: @Burninrock24 Always `print_r()` your arrays to see their structure while debugging.